# Naming convention Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I read that Rails follows some naming conventions, model name should be singular and controller name should be plural.

I have a model called `body` and i would like to know how am i supposed to name my controller's name -- should it be 'bodies' or 'bodys'??

Thanks for for any suggestion provided ;)

Sorry for this newbie question

Comment: Bodies. For the most part, Rails tries to be smart about English pluralization. To extend it, use the ActiveSupport's [Inflector support](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/Inflector/Inflections).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to be precise your model should be called 'Body' (more of a Ruby thing to capitalize class names). ActiveRecord will automagically look in the SQL table called 'bodies' for any database interaction (create, update, delete).

Your controller will be called BodiesController in a file app/controllers/bodies_controller.rb.

Answer (score 1):

following conventions `bodies`

```
class BodiesController
end
```

Comment: cool, thanks a lot for all the suggestions provided. I thought Rails would not be smart enough about English pluralization ;)

Answer (score 1):

It should be `bodies_controller`. Bodys - something from children wear stuff =)